# Innovate something or Innovate on something

Tags: adjectives

While reading I found something freak:

> With good governance structures and significant new financial grants, the selected public institutions will be able to '[ innovate on ]' courses and encourage research.

According to Oxford Advanced learner's (innovate sth)  is correct.
But here in this sentence ***innovate on*** is being used.
Is it correct?

Comment: Regardless of whether you use a preposition or not (or *which* preposition you use), I don't think ***innovate*** is a very suitable verb in the cited context. Mainstream Anglophones would probably have used ***improve, develop,*** or similar, so it was no surprise to me to discover that the cited example is ["Indian English" from ***The Hindu***.](https://www.thehindu.com/todays-paper/tp-opinion/conferring-eminence/article24415658.ece)

Answer (score 2):

Either 'innovate' or 'innovate on' can be used.

Other examples of 'innovate on', (including citation):

> How McCormick Uses Design Thinking To Innovate on Its Product Line [Citation](https://medium.com/radicle/how-mccormick-uses-design-thinking-to-innovate-on-its-product-line-c3d5ed7455e2)
>
> to introduce something new; make changes (often fol. by on or in): to innovate on another's creation [Citation](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/innovating)
>
> Instead, they create a culture in which every employee is encouraged and empowered to innovate on its processes, products, workflows or services. [Citation](https://catherinescareercorner.com/2015/07/30/how-to-innovate-and-shine-at-work-10-ways/)